# what is personGroupId in cognitive face?

Tags: image-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

what is personGroupId in cognitive face?

my error is this

---

cognitive_face.util.CognitiveFaceException: Error when calling Cognitive Face API:

```
status_code: 404
code: PersonGroupNotFound
message: Person group is not found.
Parameter name: personGroupId
```

---

### my code is

```
res = CF.person.create(personGroupId, str(sys.argv[1]))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

A person group is the container of the uploaded person data, including face images and face recognition features.

In order to create a person, you need to create a group first. You'll provide a person group id, which can be used to create a person (or more) afterwards.

You can create the group first with the following code:

```
res = CF.person_group.create('mygroup')
```

The valid characters for group id include numbers, English letters in lower case, '-' and '_'. The maximum length of the personGroupId is 64.